# How do I iterate through object array and have the results appear in a list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I am trying to create an unordered list from an array of contacts.

The array would be similar to:

```
let contacts = [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46}, {firstName:"Mike", lastName:"Smith", age:46}, {firstName:"Joe", lastName:"Dirt", age:46}];
```

I can create a list from a basic array like so:

```
var options = [
        set0 = ['Option 1','Option 2'],
    ];

function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}

// Add the contents of options[0] to #foo:
document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(makeUL(options[0]));
```

I don't quite understand how to make the list using the object.

Comment: `        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i].firstName));`

Comment: In the case of `makeUL(contacts)`, your `array[i]` would refer to the *object*. You can access individual property values of that object by doing `array[i].firstName` or `array[i].lastName`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, an object can access property by using . or [].

ex)  `array[i].firstName` or `array[i]['firstName']`

you can use Template Strings or JSON.stringify

```
const item = array[i];

item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`firstName: ${item.firstName}, lastName: ${item.lastName}`));
```

or

```
item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(array[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let contacts = [
    {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46}, 
    {firstName:"Mike", lastName:"Smith", age:46}, 
    {firstName:"Joe", lastName:"Dirt", age:46}
];

function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i].firstName + ' ' + array[i].lastName + ' ' + array[i].age));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;

}

document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(makeUL(contacts));
```

as suggested by tyler I'll add some context on the solution. I copied the same function then just used . to access the contents of the object.

Comment: Consider providing some context, explanation, etc. Code-only, "spot-the-difference" answers are rarely *good* answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in the browser console.  Not sure what you are looking for, but if you have an array of objects and want to create an ul list from that, you can try something like this:

var options = [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46}, {firstName:"Mike", lastName:"Smith", age:46}, {firstName:"Joe", lastName:"Dirt", age:46}];

```
function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        for (var key in array[i])
        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i][key] + " "));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}

// Add the contents of options[0] to #foo:

alert(makeUL(options).outerHTML);
```

That will give you something like this:

```
<ul><li>John Doe 46 </li><li>Mike Smith 46 </li><li>Joe Dirt 46 </li></ul>
```

You can probably modify that to suit your needs.

Here is another variation:

```
var options = [{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:46}, {firstName:"Mike", lastName:"Smith", age:46}, {firstName:"Joe", lastName:"Dirt", age:46}];

function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        var text = new Array();
        for (var key in array[i]) {
        // Set its contents:
        text.push(array[i][key]);
        }
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.join(",")));
        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}

// Add the contents of options[0] to #foo:

alert(makeUL(options).outerHTML);
```

Comment: I'm rethinking my approach...Please see the codepen here. https://codepen.io/aspiringpro/pen/BegJyB  

I'd like to figure out a way to get the contact data into the appropriate divs.